# Bigquery utf-8 problems

Tags: utf-8, google-bigquery

I am using google-api-services-bigquery in java to load data from JSON files stored in Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery. 
Everything was ok with this configuration:

```
    Job job = new Job();
    JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration();
    JobConfigurationLoad configLoad = new JobConfigurationLoad();
    configLoad.setSchema(schema);
    configLoad.setDestinationTable(destTable);
    configLoad.setEncoding(StringConstants.UTF_8);
    configLoad.setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED");
    configLoad.setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND");
    configLoad.setSourceFormat("NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON");
    configLoad.setAllowQuotedNewlines(false);
    configLoad.setSourceUris(gcsPaths);
    config.setLoad(configLoad);
    job.setConfiguration(config);
```

But since about 2014-01-30 12:00:00 GMT russian characters in JSON values began to be replaced by question marks. The application was working as a daemon and was not even restarted at that moment. So, I think the issue is caused by some changes in Bigquery. Bigquery now uses Latin-1?
Does anyone know, how can I solve this?

Comment: A few questions:
(1) Is this a JSON or CSV load? You said JSON in the text, but the code looks like CSV.
(2) How are you observing the character replacement? Is it possible that the encoding issue is on the way *out* rather than on the way *in*?

Comment: Sorry, posted wrong code fragment. In bigquery ui I can still get correct russian charecters for older days. Only new records are spoiled. And I also use grouping by these fields. So the data is corrupted on the way in. I have also checked input file encoding (I get the files from other service). It was not changed and it is utf-8.

Comment: Can you send me (jcondit at google.com) an example of a JSON row that fails to load properly? Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue anymore. It is somehow fixed without any changes in application code. Thanks for your replies, Jeremy.